# No Logout Visible in Rundeck GUI

Tags: logging, rundeck

I have upgraded the Rundeck to version 3.4.8. I am able to retain my Projects and execution history, but lost the node and SCM configuration(which I did manually).
The issue is now when I execute the Rundeck Jobs I cannot see Log Output in GUI. The Job is getting executed and also showing status as Successful and Failed.
When I check rundeck.execution.log I can see complete log output in that file. This file is owned by runback user and group with 755 permission.
Can anybody help me to get the log output visible in Rundeck

Comment: Hi! your instance is behind a proxy server? probably you are facing this https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/7456 (with a large output content), could you test with a job that generates a short log output like `whoami` command or something like that?

Comment: Also, if you could provide a minimal reproducible example job definition to test would be great.

Comment: Yes I can see the output if display the logs as HTML or text. The older version of Rundeck is working fine for the same jobs.
Can it be the issue with the version 3.4.8?

Comment: Ok, you can see the output following this?: 1) run the job, 2) click on the log output link (not clicking on nodes output first).

Comment: Basically this: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/7456#issuecomment-1005653511

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue. Should not say fixed corrected a silly mistake.
In grails.serverURL I have given http instead of https.
Made it https and then restarted Rundeck and yes now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Exist an identical problem [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/7456), it's a bug discovered on Rundeck 3.4.6. Right now you have two workarounds to avoid this:

1. Click the Log Output directly after the job execution (without clicking the Nodes output first).
2. Refresh the log output page.

The fix is on the way, could be ready soon.

So, if your instance is behind of a proxy server:

Make sure that `grails.serverURL` config (at `rundeck-config.properties` file) is defined with the Rundeck proxy exit URL.

Also, make sure to set `server.useForwardHeaders=true` at `rundeck-config.properties` file or `-Drundeck.jetty.connector.forwarded=true` as launch parameter, take a [look](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/6292#issuecomment-674753355).

Comment: Above both workarounds does not work for me still no output, also I checked in nodes it just says Loading but nothing comes up.
I also tried whoami in command section and there is no logout for this command as well. Only HTML and Text contains logs.

Comment: Your instance is behind a proxy server?

Comment: Yes, and I have set proxy as well

Comment: Make sure that `grails.serverURL` (at `rundeck-config.properties` file) is defined with the proxy exit url for rundeck, take a look: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/6309#issuecomment-663794232

Comment: This particular version of Rundeck had log4j vulnerability fix, so did that has something to do with it?

Comment: Rundeck 3.4.9 includes the loj4j2 2.17.0, no extra steps needed.

Comment: Important, take a look on this: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/6292#issuecomment-674753355 it seems the same problem.

Comment: Fixed the issue. Should not say fixed corrected a silly mistake. In grails.serverURL I have given http instead of https. Made it https and then restarted Rundeck and yes now it is working. 
Thanks @MegaDrive68K for all the input and sorry for the trouble

Comment: Great! Good news then, Cheers!